# SQL Statement to find unique records to tbl1 without records same that also exist in tbl2

Tags: sql

I am trying to list records in 'c' without the ones also part of 'o' but somehow my code does not work based on customerNumber.

```
select c.* 
from c 
where c.customerNumber not in (select o.customerNumber
                               from orders o 
                               inner join customers c on c.customerNumber = o.customerNumber);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with not exists:

```
select c.* from c 
where not exists (
  select 1 
  from orders 
  where customerNumber = c.customerNumber
);
```

or simplify your code:

```
select  c.* from c 
where c.customerNumber not in (
  select  customerNumber
  from orders
);
```